# What is the meaning of checking hash in the cookie when auto login using PHP

Tags: php, cookies, hash

```
$randomString = 'string';
$hash = md5($id . $randomString . $username);
setCookie('id', $id);
setCookie('username', $username);
setCookie('hash', $hash);

when auto login

if($hash == md5($id . $randomString . $username)){//auto login...}
```

The question is I retrieve id,username from cookie,and I compare the hash value retrieved from cookie with the two values I retrieved before,it means nothing.They will always be the same,is there any cases that the two value will not be the same?

So what exactly is the meaning of this if statement?For secure consideration?

Answer (score 1):

They will always be the same **unless** the `setCookie` function modifies one of `$id`, `$username` or `$hash` by reference.